# any NPM packages to convert rich text to plain text with newlines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, quill

I'm currently working on a react project in which I use Quill editor to generate rich text, that I store in a Postgresql database, but sometimes I need a plain text version of the rich text to conduct a comparison. the problem is that I found npm packages that transform rich-text into plain text but I end up with text without newlines which is a necessity for me.

I know that quill can also provide the plain text with newlines but in order to do so when I get the stored text from the database, I need to create an instance of quill editor and mount it on the DOM the call the getText() function.

here is a clarification example:

**entry:**

[illustration of the entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77zRf.png)

**generated HTML string:**

```
"<p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the </p><p>printing</p>"
```

**plain text after conversion:**

> "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of theprinting"

**plain text I would want to get:**

> "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the \nprinting\n"

is there an npm package that can do the job or I should write a function to do so.

**sorry for the long boring details, Thank you.**

Comment: That's not a normal behaviour what you want to implement.
you can handle it manually using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html-to-formatted-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-formatted-text) package.